# Execute Routine After Save

Tags: vba, visio

I need to execute a function in Visio after saving the document.
VBA for Visio has the following function for execution after save

```vb
Private Sub Document_DocumentSaved(ByVal doc As IVDocument)
    'Function Code
End Sub
```

However, this function does not execute after the save is finished, but before. I can verify this by the date of the Visio file and the Microsoft Office Upload Center, which does not start before the VBA code finished executing. (The VBA code in question is used for stuff relating to SharePoint and it is essential that the file is saved before executing the actions.)

One possible workaround is `Application.OnTime`. This function could be used before save to schedule the execution of the code after save is completed. Unfortunately, `Appication.OnTime` is not available in VBA for Visio.

Comment: I am not familiar with doing vba in visio but I know that it is possible to add vba macros to the normal.dot template for word and the personal.xlsb file for excel which allow for vba execution outside of documents which might make is possible to run code after a document save.

Comment: Other thoughts: maybe call document.save() inside your code and evaluate the return value or check if there is an error to verify save was completed OK (but you would also need to use a global variable or something to prevent it calling _DocumentSaved() event forever)?

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the file may not even go to SharePoint at the moment of saving (in case you are working offline, it can be saved locally instead). And uploaded hours later, when internet connection is back for example...

Anyways. You could try using [Application.VisioIsIdle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/visio.application.visioisidle), that is called periodically when Visio is not busy with anything else, but please note that it's called quite frequently so you'll need to add some time management yourself.